# How would you write a function from $A\sqcup B$ to $C\sqcup B$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Say you have a function $f:A\to C$. It is perfectly legitimate to write

$f\times \text{id}_B :A\times B \to C\times B$

$(a,b)\mapsto (f(a),b)$.

But what if instead of a cartesian product, you had a union? So

$f\times \text{id}_B :A\sqcup B \to C\sqcup B$

Question is: how would you write a such function?

Comment: What is the question?  Are you asking about the notation?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: Is $\sqcup$ disjoint union?

Comment: yes, disjoint union

Comment: You wouldn't write the latter function as $f\times \rm{id}_B$.  You could write it as $f\sqcup \rm{id}_B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disjoint union operation is *universal* for maps out, in the following sense.  Given any maps $f:A \to X$ and $g:B \to X$, there is a map
$$
f \sqcup g: A \sqcup B \to X,
$$
defined (in the obvious way) by
$$
(f \sqcup g)(t) = \begin{cases}
f(t) & \text{if }\, t \in A, \\
g(t) & \text{if }\, t \in B.
\end{cases}
$$
Conversely, given any map $f \sqcup g: A \sqcup B \to X$, we can recover the maps $f$ and $g$ by restriction.

This construction is an example of the [*coproduct*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct) construction in the category of sets.  Coproducts take different forms in different categories, but they are always defined by the universal mapping property described above.  Incidentally, the coproduct is *dual* to the product construction (universal for maps *in*).  The Cartesian product plays the role of product in the category of sets.

---

By the way, in your example, the second map is $\operatorname{id}_B:B \to B$, and supressing the natural embeddings $C \subseteq C \sqcup B$ and $B \subseteq C \sqcup B$, the function would be written
$$
f \sqcup \operatorname{id}_B.
$$
If we were being really careful, we'd name the embeddings
$$
\iota_C: C \hookrightarrow C \sqcup B
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\iota_B: B \hookrightarrow C \sqcup B,
$$
and the map you're interested would be the coproduct of these compositions, each of which lands in $X = C \sqcup B$:
$$
(\iota_C \circ f) \sqcup (\iota_B \circ \operatorname{id}_B).
$$
By the way, when the meaning is clear, it's typical *not* to be so careful (i.e., pedantic) in choosing notation.  But when you're first learning, it can be useful to see it written carefully.